# how can i show a Matrix in qtableview with pyqt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

i'm just to noob at pyqt, i've made my desing at qtdesigner and  i just want to display a simple matrix into qtableview with a function MostrarMem called by pushButton
THANKS!!

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

#Here is the matrix i want to show
matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(708, 557)
        self.layoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 20, 258, 227))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("layoutWidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setMargin(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.textBrowser = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self.layoutWidget)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textBrowser"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.layoutWidget1 = QtGui.QWidget(Form)
        self.layoutWidget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 361, 229))
        self.layoutWidget1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("layoutWidget1"))
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setMargin(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.tableView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableView"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_4"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 320, 175, 27))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.MostrarMem)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.tableView.reset)
        #QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_3, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), Form.slot2)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_2, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.textBrowser.clear)
        #QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_4, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), Form.slot3)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Mostrar Memoria", None))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Generar Memoria", None))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Limpiar", None))
    def MostrarMem(self):
        #here to show matrix in tableView

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys;
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The First and the last comments to work... mostly of code is the interface... thanks

Comment: I would suggest using a [QTableWidget](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html) instead, if your needs are simple. It is a QTableView with a default model built in.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a `QTableWidget`:

change: `self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self.layoutWidget1)`
by: `self.tableView = QtGui.QTableWidget(self.layoutWidget1)`

And your function should be like:

```
    def MostrarMem(self):
        self.tableView.setRowCount(len(matrix))
        self.tableView.setColumnCount(len(matrix[0]))
        for i,row in enumerate(matrix):
            for j,val in enumerate(row):
                self.tableView.setItem(i,j,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(val)))
```

The use of a `QTableWidget` is desired on this cases because you don't need to provide a model to show your data, if you use a `QTableView` you need to setup a model too which may be  desirable if your data is a little more complex than a matrix but at the cost of a few more lines of code.

You can read more about Qt's model/view programming [here](http://www.yasinuludag.com/blog/?p=98) and [here](http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/modelview/)

Comment: Can you explain why QTableWidget and not QTableView, would be useful to understand why the OP attempt did not work.